# C# MySql Unknown column in where clause

Tags: c#, mysql

After I try to output the password in the dataGrid, from the given Username in the `txt_Username` textbox, I get this error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'Test' in 'where clause'"

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Password from tbl_anmeldedaten Where Username=" + txt_Username.Text, con);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact cause of the error is that you are trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT Password
FROM tbl_anmeldedaten
WHERE Username = Test;
```

Does it look like `Test` should have single quotes around it?  Yes, it should, and you *could* add that to your raw query.  But, concatenating a query like this in C# leaves open the possibility for SQL injection.  A much better approach is to use prepared statements:

```
string sql = "SELECT Password FROM tbl_anmeldedaten WHERE Username = @val1";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, MySqlConn.conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", txt_Username.Text);
cmd.Prepare();
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) 
{
    // consume a record in the result set
}
```

Comment: Also specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is better than `AddWithValue`. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @S.Akbari That looks like a good link, but I can't edit my answer without knowing for sure what the type of the `Username` column is in the actual table.

Answer (score -1):

You are using string concatenation which is a vector for SQL injection attacks. Perhaps the username in the text field is doing some SQL which it shouldn't be allowed to (for instance `'' OR Test=1`. There are plenty of resources on using parameterized queries which should remedy the problem.

Comment: that's a comment, not the answer

Comment: @Dr.Snail sometimes the answer can be achieved more without showing code.

Comment: see Tim's answer or https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for further help